# JSON Serialization Output Contains Count Property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, arrays, json

I'm trying to serialize an array of objects into JSON in C#. By array I mean something like `Object[]` (not `Array<Object>`), I'm using a JsonMediaTypeFormatter as part of MVC (the serialization is happening automatically as part of the framework but I can override it). The output contains `{"count":2,"value":[{...},{...},...]}"` where the ... is the json representation of the object. I've looked around and haven't found much information about suppressing this behavior. I want the output to just be the `[{...},{...},...]` rather than the object with `count` and `values` properties. Does anyone know how to achieve this without manually writing the code to do the serialization?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider an alternative framework like the [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) framework.  I don't know how much you can customize if you are using an in-built .NET object since there are public properties that are not being ignored.  Not using the JSONMediaTypeFormatter much, if it allows you to ignore properties, consider overriding List or ArrayList to hide certain attributes.

I would recommend not returning an array directly as there is a security flaw that could be compromised in a client browser (if that is the consumer).  See this [reference](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx) to find out more.

Comment: Thanks, I basically ended up using another framework to serialize it and constructed the HttpResponseMessage manually. The array requirement is not by choice some other API I am hooking into requires it to be in that format.